# Proving the closedness of given sets

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I want to show that the sets
$\{(x, y):xy = 1\} $ and $\{(x, y):x^2+y^2 = 1 \} $ are closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Geometrically, it is clear that both sets contains all of its limit points in $\mathbb{R}^2$, hence closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$ . I want show them by the help of continuous maps. 
Could anybody give me any idea or help to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the simple solution.

Let $f : X \to Y$ a continuous function hence $f^{-1}(C)$ is closed in $X$ when
ever $C$ is closed in $Y$ . Let  $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to\mathbb{ R} $ be defined by $f(x,y) = xy$.
Clearly $f$ is continuous and $\{1\}$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{ R}$ hence 
Then $f^{-1}({1}) = \{(x, y):xy = 1\} $ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$.
Similarly, define  $g : \mathbb{R}^2 \to\mathbb{ R} $ be  by $g(x,y) = x^2+y^2$
then $g^{-1}(1) = \{(x, y):x^2+y^2 \} $ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$.